# jQuery UI Tab screen jump automatic scroll to bottom of window drives me nuts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

i'm using jQuery ui tab solution exactly as it is stated here http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/XHD5N/

everything works fine, except if i have a tab that has a lot of data, the browser will automatically scroll to the bottom of the window to show the content on the tab..

how do i keep the tabs in the same position regardless of how much data is on the tab? the tabs jumping up and down depending on the height of the tab drives me crazy - i have some data on the page above the tabs, so the tabs will be positioned half way on the screen (i want the tab to remain half way on the screen regardless of what's on the tab)

here is the full source code you can copy and paste test in your browser, please help!! ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by fordlover49</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>


   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            panelTemplate: "<iframe style='width:100%; border=0; height:500px'></iframe>",
            idPrefix: "ui-tabs-",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                if (!$("#ui-tabs-" + ui.index).prop("src")) {
                  $("#ui-tabs-" + ui.index).attr("src", $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs'));  
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="test" style="height:500px;">dummy</div>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <li><a id="recent-tab" href="#ui-tabs-0">Amazon</a></li>
        <li><a id="popular-tab" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a id="random-tab" href="http://www.jsfiddle.net">jsfiddle</a></li>
        <li><a id="question-tab" href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="ui-tabs-0"> Select a tab, and watch it load!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `the browser will automatically scroll to the bottom of the window to show the content on the tab`? Why does the browser do this?

Comment: just copy the code and save it as html and view it in the browser, you will see what I mean. basically the tab would not stay in the middle of the screen, will go up or down in the browser depending on how much data is in the tab. if i look at the vertical scroll bar on the browser, it's always scrolled to the bottom..

Comment: can anybody help? this seem something simple but i can't figure it out for the life of me.. :)